# A woman is full of needs

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-request

I was wondering how should I imply naturally that "a woman is full of needs" in English? 
Is it natural by itself or it sounds vague to you?
I would appreciate it if you let me know that it is natural in my made-up context:

> **Son)** Dad, if you don't mind, I wanna marry my girlfriend Tania! 
>   **Dad)** Whatever you say son, but I think still it's a bit early for you! 
>   **Son)** How come dad? Why do you think like that? 
>   **Dad)** Listen Billy; I know that you love her! But **a woman is full of needs.** First, you should be able to fulfill her needs and meet her demands. Here is the rub! I think you're not still ready to bear the burden of a family on your own!

Comment: I do think it is vague and liable to be misinterpreted. Humans have many types of needs, emotional, economic, sexual. Which of these burdens does the father think his son lacks the capacity to shoulder?

Comment: Good question. All possible needs @Jeff Morrow. of course the father is more about "economic" and "emotional" needs.

Comment: Isn't 'a woman is full of needs' rather sexist, or is that off-topic here?

Comment: @Michael Harvey, that is not at all about sexism, but in some eastern ideologies, women as mothers of human, are considered gentler creatures which should be cared. For instance as you know there are many poems in some cultures in which women have been compared to 'flowers' which certainly need to be cared and loved. This is not sexism, this is nature. Each gender is respectable for its own particular specifications and qualities. Perhaps women for their delicacy and unique beauty as it is in men in manly way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's vague. If you wanted to be more clear you could state the needs you're talking about, either in the same sentence or the next sentence, but I don't think it's necessary.

> A woman is full of needs, like shelter, clothes and support for her children.

Just a tip: 'wanna' is not a word in written English. It's a slang contraction for 'want to'. However, since you're writing dialog you might get away with using it as a way to accurately portray the sound of the conversation. In the same way, it's a little awkward to start a sentence with 'But' when you're writing, and since this is dialog it is acceptable.

Comment: Well @dwilli don't you think it is better to say: "full of needs and demands" rather than simply say: "needs"?

Comment: Not necessarily @A-friend. I don't think it's any better or any worse. This is dialog, so it's okay if it's not exactly consistent like that.